# Entity resolution - creating a unique identifier based on 3 columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to find a way to create a unique identifier by using 3 columns (user_id, universal_id and session_id). Column "expected_result" is what this unique_id should be after processing other 3 columns.

- Sometimes user_id is not available, and in that case the other two columns should be used to create the unique id.
- When user_id doesn't have a match and universal_id has a match, those should be treated as different (separate unique id).
- "id" column is the order in which data is written into the database. If a new row shows up that matches any of the previous rows (with already calculated unique id) by any of the 3 columns, the already existing unique id should be added to the new row.

Here's a list of possible relationships between columns:

- user_id:universal_id = 1:N OR N:1 (if N:1 then each N needs a unique_id)
- user_id:session_id = 1:N
- universal_id:session_id = 1:N or N:1

I'm trying to find a thing in python (or pyspark because I may be using this on millions of rows) that can help me do the clustering of this data (or however this process is called in data science). The idea is to create a map of universal_id:unique_id. If you know how this is done please help, or at least point me to a subject that I should research to be able to do this. Thanks!

I have Snowflake and Databricks at my disposal.

Here's my test dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 1, 'apple', 'fiat', 1],
    [2, 1, 'pear', 'bmw', 1],
    [3, 2, 'bananna', 'citroen', 2],
    [4, 3, 'bananna', 'kia', 3],
    [5, 4, 'blueberry', 'peugeot', 4],
    [6, None, 'blueberry', 'peugeot', 4],
    [7, None, 'blueberry', 'yamaha', 4],
    [8, 5, 'plum', 'ford', 5],
    [9, None, 'watermelon', 'ford', 5],
    [10, None, 'raspberry', 'honda', 6],
    [11, None, 'raspberry', 'toyota', 6],
    [12, None, 'avocado', 'mercedes', 7],
    [13, None, 'cherry', 'mercedes', 7],
    [14, None, 'apricot', 'volkswagen', 2],
    [15, 2, 'apricot', 'volkswagen', 2],
    [16, 6, 'blueberry', 'audi', 8],
    [17, None, 'blackberry', 'bmw', 1],
    [18, 7, 'plum', 'porsche', 9]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'user_id', 'universal_id', 'session_id', 'expected_result'])
```

Comment: Hi! Looking at the updated dataset, I have a question I cannot get my head around: Why are the rows with `id==6` and `id==7` grouped together with row `id==5` but **not** with the row `id==16`?

Comment: @SimonGsponer that is an error that I have in my data which I reproduced here because I need to account for it as well: some universal_ids have multiple user_ids tied to them. In this case, I assigned it in part arbitrarily, and in part because of the sorting, the expected_result==4 would first be recorded for id==5, then on the next iteration the id==6 row would match by universal_id and session_id with id==5 and it would collect its expected_result value.

Comment: ok understood, thanks for sharing! let me adjust my solution to accommodate for this

Comment: Hi! Updated my answer and also included some additional code regarding my answer I gave earlier to you on UUID1 and UUID4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, we can formulate an algorithm as follows, referring to the new ID as `global_id`. **Update:** The algorithm now features the arbitrary tie-break when multiple `user_id`s match multiple `universal_id`s. **Update:** Since you were concerned about the risk of duplicates using fully randomly generated UUID4s, I coded you a little function which allows you to generate a UUID leveraging both UUID1 and/or UUID4 - I personally would not be worried about clashes of UUID4 values whatsoever, but it's up to you.

1. Create a new `global_id` for every `user_id` **that has
   multiple occurrences** (n>1)
2. Propagate values for `global_id` to all rows with matching
   `user_id`
3. Create a new `global_id` for every `user_id` **that has single occurrence** (n=1)
4. Propagate values for `global_id` to all rows with matching `universal_id`, i.e. rows which don't match on `user_id` but match on `universal_id`. **There is an arbitrary tie break** if multiple `universal_id`s match on one or more `user_id`s, where all matching `universal_id`s are assigned to the same `user_id`
5. Create a new `global_id` for every `universal_id` which
   cannot be  linked to a `user_id` **but has multiple occurrences**
   (n>1)
6. Propagate values for `global_id` to all rows with
   matching `universal_id`
7. Propagate existing values for `global_id` to all rows  with matching `session_id`, i.e. rows with don't match on neither `user_id` or `universal_id` but on `session_id`
8. Create a new `global_id` for every `session_id` which cannot
   be linked to neither a `user_id` nor `universal_id` **but has
   multiple occurrences** (n>1)
9. Propagate values for `global_id` to all rows with matching `session_id`
10. (not needed in your example but might be useful): Create a
    new `global_id` for every session_id which does **not** have
    multiple occurrences (n=1)

Hope this helps!

```
import uuid
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = [
    [1, 1, 'apple', 'fiat', 1],
    [2, 1, 'pear', 'bmw', 1],
    [3, 2, 'bananna', 'citroen', 2],
    [4, 3, 'bananna', 'kia', 3],
    [5, 4, 'blueberry', 'peugeot', 4],
    [6, None, 'blueberry', 'peugeot', 4],
    [7, None, 'blueberry', 'yamaha', 4],
    [8, 5, 'plum', 'ford', 5],
    [9, None, 'watermelon', 'ford', 5],
    [10, None, 'raspberry', 'honda', 6],
    [11, None, 'raspberry', 'toyota', 6],
    [12, None, 'avocado', 'mercedes', 7],
    [13, None, 'cherry', 'mercedes', 7],
    [14, None, 'apricot', 'volkswagen', 2],
    [15, 2, 'apricot', 'volkswagen', 2],
    [16, 6, 'blueberry', 'audi', 8],
    [17, None, 'blackberry', 'bmw', 1],
    [18, 7, 'plum', 'porsche', 9]
]


def generate_uuid(use_uuid1: bool=True, use_uuid4: bool=False) -> str:
    """Helper function creating UUIDs.
    
    Arguments:
        use_uuid1: Whether generated UUID string should feature a UUID1 part.
            Defaults to `True`.
        use_uuid1: Whether generated UUID string should feature a UUID4 part.
            Defaults to `False`.
    
    Returns:
        Universally unique identifier based on UUID1 and/or UUID4.
    """
    uuid_str = ""

    if not use_uuid1 and not use_uuid4:
        raise ValueError("Both use_uuid1 and use_uuid4 are set to `False`, cannot create UUID.")

    elif use_uuid1 and use_uuid4:
        uuid_str += f"{str(uuid.uuid1())}-{str(uuid.uuid4())}"
    elif use_uuid1:
        uuid_str += str(uuid.uuid1())
    else:
        uuid_str += str(uuid.uuid4())
    
    return uuid_str


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'user_id', 'universal_id', 'session_id', 'expected_result'])

# STEP 1
df.sort_values(by='user_id', inplace=True)
df['_same_user_id'] = (
    (df['user_id'] == df['user_id'].shift(-1))
    & (df['user_id'] != df['user_id'].shift(1))
)
df['global_id'] = [generate_uuid() if value else np.NaN for value in df['_same_user_id'].values]

# STEP 2
df['global_id'] = df.groupby('user_id')['global_id'].ffill()

# STEP 3
df['_new_ids'] = [generate_uuid() if not np.isnan(value) else np.NaN for value in df['user_id'].values]
df['global_id'].fillna(df['_new_ids'], inplace=True)

# # STEP 4
df.sort_values(by='universal_id', inplace=True)
df['global_id'] = df.groupby('universal_id')['global_id'].ffill()

# STEP 5
df['_count_universal_id'] = df['universal_id'].groupby(df['universal_id']).transform('count')
df['_same_universal_id'] = (
    (df['universal_id'] == df['universal_id'].shift(-1))
    & (df['universal_id'] != df['universal_id'].shift(1))
)
df['_new_id_for_universal_id'] = (
    df['_count_universal_id'].gt(1)
    & (df['global_id'].isnull()) 
    & df['_same_universal_id']
)
df['_new_ids'] = [generate_uuid() if value else np.NaN for value in df['_new_id_for_universal_id'].values]
df['global_id'].fillna(df['_new_ids'], inplace=True)

# STEP 6
df['global_id'] = df.groupby('universal_id')['global_id'].ffill()


# STEP 7
df.sort_values(by='session_id', inplace=True)
df['global_id'] = df.groupby('session_id')['global_id'].ffill()

# STEP 8
df['_count_session_id'] = df['session_id'].groupby(df['session_id']).transform('count')
df['_same_session_id'] = (
    (df['session_id'] == df['session_id'].shift(-1))
    & (df['session_id'] != df['session_id'].shift(1))
)
df['_new_id_for_session_id'] = (
    df['_count_session_id'].gt(1)
    & (df['global_id'].isnull()) 
    & df['_same_session_id']
)
df['_new_ids'] = [generate_uuid() if value else np.NaN for value in df['_new_id_for_session_id'].values]
df['global_id'].fillna(df['_new_ids'], inplace=True)

# STEP 9
df['global_id'] = df.groupby('session_id')['global_id'].ffill()

# STEP 10
df['_new_ids'] = [generate_uuid() if value == 1 else np.NaN for value in df['_count_session_id'].values]
df['global_id'].fillna(df['_new_ids'], inplace=True)

# DROP INTERNAL COLUMNS
cols_to_drop = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("_")]
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
```

Results (since we're now using UUID1, the ID's look very similar but they are not the same).

```
|   id |   user_id | universal_id   | session_id   |   expected_result | global_id                            |
|-----:|----------:|:---------------|:-------------|------------------:|:-------------------------------------|
|    2 |         1 | pear           | bmw          |                 1 | ee52b80a-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   17 |       nan | blackberry     | bmw          |                 1 | ee52b80a-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    1 |         1 | apple          | fiat         |                 1 | ee52b80a-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    3 |         2 | bananna        | citroen      |                 2 | ee52ba1c-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   14 |       nan | apricot        | volkswagen   |                 2 | ee52ba1c-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   15 |         2 | apricot        | volkswagen   |                 2 | ee52ba1c-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    4 |         3 | bananna        | kia          |                 3 | ee530d00-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    5 |         4 | blueberry      | peugeot      |                 4 | ee530e04-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    6 |       nan | blueberry      | peugeot      |                 4 | ee530e04-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    7 |       nan | blueberry      | yamaha       |                 4 | ee530e04-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    9 |       nan | watermelon     | ford         |                 5 | ee530f08-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|    8 |         5 | plum           | ford         |                 5 | ee530f08-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   16 |         6 | blueberry      | audi         |                 8 | ee53100c-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   18 |         7 | plum           | porsche      |                 9 | ee531106-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   10 |       nan | raspberry      | honda        |                 6 | ee54a002-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   11 |       nan | raspberry      | toyota       |                 6 | ee54a002-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   13 |       nan | cherry         | mercedes     |                 7 | ee567260-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
|   12 |       nan | avocado        | mercedes     |                 7 | ee567260-f0da-11ed-8f35-0242ac1c000c |
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a mistake in the original test dataset expected_result, but fixed it now. Each user_id should have its own global_id which was not right in my original dataset and in your solution. I'm also wondering if uuid is a good solution since there's a chance for duplicates, this script is supposed to get hundreds of thousands of rows each day and compare them to all data entered on previous days, and this has no way of checking if new global_id is a duplicate of previously created one.

Comment: Ok, let me get back to you later today on those points

Comment: Hi @mare011 - of course, you could also think about creating an ID using UUID1, which generates a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time (see documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) on `uuid.uuid1`) - if you really worried about duplicates and want to hedge your bets you could in theory create a "combined ID" by generating both a UUID1 and a UUID4 and concatenating them - admittedly you'd get a large ID but you would also eliminate any conceivable risk of duplication